# How can I get polar coordinates represented properly?

Tags: actionscript-3, geometry, polar-coordinates

I have the following hexagonal grid and trying to calculate the degrees to each edge hexagon from the center (light blue):
[image]

The blue highlighted hex is correct at 0 degrees and that quadrant (lower right) is correct. Here is my angle calculation method:

```
private static function calculateAngle(hex1:Hexagon, hex2:Hexagon):Number {
    // hex1 is always passed in as the grid center or start
    var diffY:Number = Math.abs(hex2.center.y) - Math.abs(hex1.center.y);
    var diffX:Number = Math.abs(hex2.center.x) - Math.abs(hex1.center.x);
    var radians:Number = Math.atan(diffY / diffX);

    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Why are the remaining angles (text in each hexagon) incorrect?

Comment: Are the `center` properties `Point` objects?

Comment: @null: yes the `center` is a `Point` object.

Comment: Thought there was a getter for the angle in the [`Point`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html), but there's only a static method `polar(len:Number, angle:Number):Point` to construct a `Point` from polar coordinates. No built in way to get the polar coordinates of an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close to correct; you just need to compensate for the periodicity of `atan`. The standard way to do this is to use [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/atan2), which returns a signed angle in `(-pi, pi]` instead of an unsigned angle in `[0, pi)`. You can do so like this:

```
var radians:Number = Math.atan2(
    hex2.center.y - hex1.center.y, hex2.center.x - hex1.center.x);
```

Note that I didn't include the call to `abs` in there: the signedness of those values is needed for `atan2` to know which quadrant its in!

Edit: if you're looking for an angle in `[0, pi]`, which represents the minimum angle between the center hex and the blue-highlighted hex, you can just take the absolute value of the result of `atan2`: `return Math.abs(radians) * 180 / Math.PI`; the question leaves it a little unclear as to which one you're asking for.

Comment: I did this but left angles that should be `> 180` as negative: `-173`, `-166` ... `-6`. So I *normalized*: `if (radians < 180) return radians + 360`